Youtube videos cannot resume after the 2024 November update
After the Android Youtube app updated a few days ago on November 7th 2024, I have been having these two problems:

Pressing back arrow from video view, the mini player disappears outside the screen but audio keeps playing.
After pausing the video, it refuses to continue.

I see from Google Play reviews that some other users are also having these problems, but not all. In case it matters, I'm using Oneplus Nord CE 5G and running OxygenOS/Android 13.

The solution turned out to be very simple:
Open Youtube application settings, force it to stop and remove both cache and data.
If you are logged into Youtube, it saves your viewing history in the cloud, so you won't lose it even if you delete the data. You do have to login again after this.
